# UIScrollView constraints problems

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to understand well Xcode's autolayout constraints, but I immediately encountered an error with UIScrollView constraints.
I set up a UIScrollView with 4 constraints: each with value 0 to its parent. Next I set up an UIView as content holder with the same constraints of the UIScrollView, but I receive the following error:

> ScrollView: Need constraints for: X position or width
>
> ScrollView: Need constraints for: Y position or height

I already set up this constraints for the scrollview ( 0,0,0,0 to its parent).

[image: Constraints and red line errors]

Why Xcode tell me this? Thanks in advance.

**Update**

Fixed setting `View.centerX = ScrollView.centerX` and `View.centerY = ScrollView.centerY`. But why those constraints are necessary?

Comment: Look at the error message: "X position _or width_". "Y position _or height_". As soon as you use auto layout with a content view in this way, you are responsible for telling the scroll view its `contentSize` thru the size of the content view. But you have not given your content view any size; it is missing width and height constraints, nor has it any subviews whose constraints can size the content view from the inside out.

Comment: Nice reply, thank you!